# Channel Deadlock in Go

Tags: go

I am getting "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
" for some reason in the below code. I am using buffered channel which should be non-blocking. Not sure what I am doing wrong

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 2)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go doSomething(c, wg)
    go doSomething(c, wg)
    go doSomething(c, wg)

    wg.Wait()

    close(c)

    for v := range c {
        fmt.Print(v)
    }

}

func doSomething(c chan<- int, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    c <- 1

}
```

Playground link https://play.golang.org/p/J9meD5aKna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your solution might work I'm not happy with it.

First, the fact that you need to change the channel size to make it work indicates that there is a potential problem / bug. Now each time you want to launch another `doSomething` you have to remember to change channel's length.

Second, you wait until all the goroutines are finished before reading from the channel. This is kind of "waste" as one of the main points of range loop over an channel is that you don't have to wait until all the items are generated (written into channel), you can start processing the items as soon as some of them are ready.

So I would write your code as something like

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)
    go func() {
        doSomething(c)
        defer wg.Done()
    }()
    go func() {
        doSomething(c)
        defer wg.Done()
    }()
    go func() {
        doSomething(c)
        defer wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        defer close(c)
    }()

    for v := range c {
        fmt.Print(v)
    }
}

func doSomething(c chan<- int) {
    c <- 1
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/T3dfiztKot

Note how the waiting and closing the channel is now in it's own goroutine - this allows to start iterating over the channel (which is now unbuffered!) right away.

I also changed the code so that the `WaitGroup` never leaves the scope where it is declared (ie it isn't used as parameter), this is my personal preference. I believe it makes code easier to follow and understand.

Comment: I thought you cannot range over channel until the channel is closed. Maybe I am wrong but that is what it says here http://guzalexander.com/2013/12/06/golang-channels-tutorial.html "As was mentioned above the range will work until the channel is closed explicitly". In this case we need to wait for the other goroutine to be executed anyway.

Comment: You misunderstood - the point is that the loop wouldn't end until the channel is closed. So if the channel is never closed you would have infinite loop (it would wait for the next item or the closing of the channel).

Comment: oh ok, so you mean the for range will block till the channel is closed. I think then your solution is better

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Actually two problems

1. The size of the channel and wg should be 3
2. I should pass the wg as pointer

Updated code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 3)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)

    go doSomething(c, &wg)
    go doSomething(c, &wg)
    go doSomething(c, &wg)

    wg.Wait()

    close(c)

    for v := range c {
        fmt.Print(v)
    }

}

func doSomething(c chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    c <- 1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an important ***issues*** in your code.

you call `go doSomething(c, wg)` just pass `wg` value.
you should know

> Arguments in Go are always passed by value. Use a pointer when an
>   argument may be modified.

so you should do like this `go doSomething(c, &wg)`, then `wg` in `main` function will be modified by `defer wg.Done()` in `func doSomething(c chan<- int, wg sync.WaitGroup)`.

.